# My WP8 game isn't receiving Drag gestures when using MonoGame

Tags: windows-phone-8, monogame

I've got a WP8 project that is using the MonoGame framework.  I have some code that should recognize Horizontal and Vertical drag events and perform an action but I never seem to get these events.  I do get a FreeDrag gesture but the Deltas are always NaN.

I initialize the TouchPanel.EnabledGestures in the Initialize method of the game as follows:

```
  protected override void Initialize()
  {
     // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
     base.Initialize();

     TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.HorizontalDrag | GestureType.FreeDrag;
  }
```

I have a method that checks the gesture type as follows:

```
  private void CheckUserGesture()
  {
     while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
     {
        var gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

        switch(gesture.GestureType)
        {
           case GestureType.DragComplete:
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Drag Complete");
              break;

           case GestureType.FreeDrag:
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Drag Complete");
              break;

           case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
              if (gesture.Delta.X < 0)
                 gameVm.MoveLeft(Math.Abs((int)gesture.Delta.X));
              if (gesture.Delta.X > 0)
                 gameVm.MoveRight((int)gesture.Delta.X);

              break;

           case GestureType.VerticalDrag:
              if (gesture.Delta.Y > 0)
                 gameVm.MoveDown(Math.Abs((int)gesture.Delta.Y));
              break;

           case GestureType.Tap:
              System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Rotating Shape Due To Tap Command");
              gameVm.RotateClockwise();
              break;
        }
     }
  }
```

And this is called in the Update method:

```
  protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
  {
     base.Update(gameTime);

     // TODO: Add your update logic here
     //CheckTouchGesture();
     CheckUserGesture();
     gameVm.UpdateGame((int)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds);
  }
```

I've also tried using TouchState:

```
  private void CheckTouchGesture()
  {
     var touchCol = TouchPanel.GetState();

     foreach (var touch in touchCol)
     {
        // You're looking for when they finish a drag, so only check
        // released touches.
        if (touch.State != TouchLocationState.Released)
           continue;

        TouchLocation prevLoc;

        // Sometimes TryGetPreviousLocation can fail. Bail out early if this happened
        // or if the last state didn't move
        if (!touch.TryGetPreviousLocation(out prevLoc) || prevLoc.State != TouchLocationState.Moved)
           continue;

        // get your delta
        var delta = touch.Position - prevLoc.Position;

        // Usually you don't want to do something if the user drags 1 pixel.
        if (delta.LengthSquared() < DragTolerence)
           continue;

        if (delta.X < 0)
           gameVm.MoveLeft(Math.Abs((int)delta.X));
        else if (delta.X > 0)
           gameVm.MoveRight((int)delta.X);
        else if (delta.Y > 0)
           gameVm.MoveDown((int)delta.Y);
     }
  }
```

But again the deltas are always NaN.

Is there something I'm missing that I might need to initialize?
I've tried various combinations of the EnabledGestures types but still can't get the dragging events to work.  Flick doesn't work either.

Things like Tap are fine though.

Thanks

Comment: Just found this bug report:
http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/431035

Wonder whether it's this issue I'm hitting.  I'm on version 3.0.1 which is the latest downloadable version on the web page.

Comment: I've done a Git Clone from the develop branch of Monogame and a Git Clone from the master branch of SharpDX.  Rebuilt both projects and referenced the built binaries and now I am getting the drag events.

Hoorah.

Hopefully MonoGame will do another release fairly soon.

Comment: I think you should add your above comment as an answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is broken on the current release of MonoGame ( Version 3.0.1, Release date: Mar 3 2013 ).

Building the latest from the GitHub developer branch:
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame.git

(NOTE: I also built SharpDX too from here: https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX)

Seems to fix a lot of my problems

I'm not 100% convinced it is fully working though.
Using the touch.TryGetPreviousLocation() as shown in the code above always returns the same position as the current position so doing var delta = loc.Position - preLoc.Postion always results in 0.

At least I'm receiving the drag gestures now.